# Regular expression for preg_replace with a certain number of characters

Tags: regex

I have a variable with something like this:

```
text1 http://www.server.com/10characters text2 http://www.server.com/10characters text3
```

I want to preg_replace all "http://www.server.com/10characters" to link "Click", but "http://www.server.com/" is a constant that must occur and "10characters" is always any 10 characters (no less, no more)

For ex.
replace

```
text1 http://www.server.com/d19d2aj53f text2 http://www.server.com/a49ds5j3ax text3
http://www.otherserver.com/a49ds5j3ax text3
```

to

```
text1 <a href="http://www.server.com/d19d2aj53f">Click</a> text2
<a href="http://www.server.com/a49ds5j3ax">Click</a>
text3 http://www.otherserver.com/xt92s5sfa2 text3
```

I have no idea how to do it :/ I tried several ways, but with no good results.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always 10 chars after the domain, you don't need for preg_replace:

```
$url1 = substr($url,0,35); //length of http://www.server.com/10characters is 35 chars
echo "text1 <a href=\"$url1\">click</a><br>";
/// etc
```

Comment: But it must find and replace all http:/www.server.com/10characters to links, not one. In text you can have even 3 or more of it.

Comment: @user1604488 you can run it in a loop ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
preg_replace("http://www\.server\.com/[0-9a-zA-Z]{10}", " Click!", $myLink)
```

should work.

Comment: Don't forget [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) and escaping your `.`s. Also, the examples seem to indicate that the ten characters are not limited to digits.

Comment: I could explain it bad, but I want it to replaced be like this:
<a href="http:/www.server.com/[.*]{10}">Click!</a>

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'text1 http://www.server.com/d19d2aj53f text2 http://www.server.com/a49ds5j3ax text3 http://www.otherserver.com/a49ds5j3ax text3';

echo preg_replace('~http://www\.server\.com/.{10}~i', '<a href="$0">click</a>', $str);
```

In the pattern, `.` is "any character", so `.{10}` means any ten characters.

In the replacement, `$0` represents what was matched by the entire pattern (in this case, the full URL).

Here's [a working example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/kwACDS) of this.